# jQuery does not calculate Value Added Tax on Form

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have added this field to my form in order to calculate value added tax (vat):

```
<div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="form-check">
        <input type="radio" id="vat_on" name="vat" value="on" checked>
        <label class="form-check-label">
        Calculate value added tax  
        </label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-check">
        <input type="radio" id="vat_off" name="vat" value="off">
        <label class="form-check-label">
            Do not calculate value added tax
        </label>
    </div>
</div>
```

And I tried adding this as jQuery:

```
if($('[name=vat]:checked').val() === 'on'){
   var value_added_tax = ((price_final*cnt) - ((price_final*cnt)*0.9)).toLocaleString();
}else{
   var value_added_tax = (0).toLocaleString();
}
```

But when I test this and checked the `Calculate value added tax` radio button, it returns: *Nan* !

However it should be returning a value instead of *Nan*.

I have also tried removing `toLocaleString()` from both conditions, but didn't solve the problem.

So what is going wrong here ? How can I fix this issue ?

I would really appreciate any idea or suggestion from you guys...

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what is `price_final ,cnt` in your code ? Please show entire code .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code quite seems ok. Please check the value of `price_final` and `cnt`.

```js
let price_final = 100, cnt = 3;
$(document).on('click','[name=vat]',function(){
  if($('[name=vat]:checked').val() === 'on'){
     var value_added_tax = ((price_final*cnt) - ((price_final*cnt)*0.9)).toLocaleString();
  }else{
     var value_added_tax = (0).toLocaleString();
  }
  console.log(value_added_tax)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="form-check">
        <input type="radio" id="vat_on" name="vat" value="on" checked>
        <label class="form-check-label">
        Calculate value added tax  
        </label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-check">
        <input type="radio" id="vat_off" name="vat" value="off">
        <label class="form-check-label">
            Do not calculate value added tax
        </label>
    </div>
</div>
```